# Table layout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement the table layout.In that I want to implement two row so I have code this as follow but it is showing force to close .can any one help on this i am stuck on this from five days

```
public  class SongsActivity extends Activity{

    DemoView demoview ;
    DemoView2 finalview;
    DemoView3 dview;
    DemoView4 deview;

    ViewFlipper c ;
    TableLayout d;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songs_layout);
        demoview = new DemoView(this);
        finalview = new DemoView2(this);
        dview= new DemoView3(this);
        deview = new DemoView4(this);
         d= new TableLayout(this);


        c=( ViewFlipper )findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        c.addView(demoview,0);
        c.addView(finalview, 1);
        c.addView(dview, 2);
        c.addView(deview, 3);
        c.setAutoStart(true);
        c.setFlipInterval(500);
        c.startFlipping();



        TableRow rw1=new TableRow(this);
         TableRow rw2=new TableRow(this);
         TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();  
         params.span = 6;
        rw1.addView(c);
        //rw2.addView();
        d.addView(rw2);
        d.addView(rw1);
        setContentView(d);
    }
```

my xml file of the layout which is used in the program is as follow

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ViewFlipper>


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

my log cat file is as follow which is showing error

```
03-25

     20:56:35.963: E/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtablayout/com.example.androidtablayout.SongsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.example.androidtablayout.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:36)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    03-25 21:01:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  ... 18 more
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtablayout/com.example.androidtablayout.SongsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.example.androidtablayout.SongsActivity.onCreate(SongsActivity.java:51)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    03-25 21:42:25.942: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  ... 18 more
```

Comment: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Problem with LinearLayout. Show all your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a row on top of the previous one that's why you are getting a runtime error.
Firstly remove your first row and then add the other one.The error is pretty clear at stack trace.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Comment: can you explain this i am not getting that ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but it's crashing because you're trying to add the ViewFlipper to the TableRow, but it's already been "added" to the activity layout (in the xml).

It's this line: `rw1.addView(c);`

Comment: can you elaborate your answer .if i will not add the view flipper then how it will work

Comment: i want to create two row.In the row 1 i want to us viewflipper and in the second i want to use the 3d image .